# Filter items from linking table

Tags: mysql

I have been looking around a lot but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem.

Here is the problem:
I have 2 mysql tables: items and tags. I assign multiple tags to 1 item by using a third table (linking table) (see table design below).

Now I am trying to design a query that filters the items based on the tags that are assigned in the linking table. It has to be AND for some tags and OR for others. For example I would like to get those items that have tag 1 or (2 and 3) assigned to them.

```
Items:
    +----+-------------+---------+
    | ID |Title        |Info     |
    +----+-------------+---------+
    |  1 | Hello world | Address |
    +----+-------------+---------+
    |  2 | Foo         | Address |
    +----+-------------+---------+

Tags:
    +----+-------+
    | ID | Name  |
    +----+-------+
    |  1 | Tag 1 |
    +----+-------+
    |  2 | Tag 2 |
    +----+-------+
    |  3 | Tag 3 |
    +----+-------+
    |  4 | Tag 4 |
    +----+-------+

Linking table:

    +----+--------+-------+
    | ID | ItemID | TagID |
    +----+--------+-------+
    |  1 |      1 |     1 |
    +----+--------+-------+
    |  2 |      1 |     2 |
    +----+--------+-------+
    |  3 |      2 |     4 |
    +----+--------+-------+
```

I cannot come up with the right query to do so. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what you way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items i 
WHERE
ID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM Linking WHERE TagID = 1)
OR (
  ID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM Linking WHERE TagID = 2)
  AND ID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM Linking WHERE TagID = 3)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

Join the tables. After that add your conditions

```
select title from linkingtable l inner join items i on l.itemid-i.id
inner join tag t on l.tagid=t.id where t.id=1 or (t.id=2 and t.id=3)
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some exlaination to your intension.